# WPF DataGrid set the EnableRowVirtualization is true, the checkbox cannot be obtained

Tags: c#, wpf

I have more than 1000 pieces of data to display in WPF's DataGrid, and I have added a check box to the DataGrid. When multiple check boxes are selected, the selected index can be added to the specified set. The code is as follows:

XAML：

```
<DataGrid x:Name="textWmdg" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding waterTexts}" Height="252" **EnableRowVirtualization="True"**
CanUserSortColumns="False"  Margin="2,2,2,2"  
VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" RowHeaderWidth="0"
CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}"VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" DataGrid.RowHeight="22" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible" LoadingRow="TextWmdg_LoadingRow">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Select" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                          <CheckBox x:Name="textSelect" Click="TextSelected_Click"/>
                     </StackPanel>
                 </DataTemplate>
             </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="NO." Width="*" Binding="{Binding Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}, Mode=FindAncestor}}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
              <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Color" Width="3*" IsReadOnly="True">
                  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                               <Label Width="15" BorderThickness="0.5" BorderBrush="Black" Background="{Binding TextColor}"/>
                           </StackPanel>
                       </DataTemplate>
                   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
               <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sign" Width="3*" Binding="{Binding Sign}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
               <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="KeyWord" Width="12*" IsReadOnly="True">
                   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShowText}" TextAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                             <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShowText}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                             </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                             </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                   </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
             </DataGrid>
```

CS:

```
private void TextSelected_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    deltextindex.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < textWmdg.Items.Count; i++)
    {

        DataGridTemplateColumn selectcolumn = textWmdg.Columns[0] as DataGridTemplateColumn;

        FrameworkElement selectment = selectcolumn.GetCellContent(textWmdg.Items[i]);

        CheckBox textcheckbox = selectcolumn.CellTemplate.FindName("textSelect", selectment) as CheckBox;

        if (textcheckbox.IsChecked == true)
        {
            deltextindex.Add(i);
        }
    }

}
```

There has been no problem before, but the display speed is very slow. Today, in order to pursue faster speed, **I set the EnableRowVirtualization of DataGrid to true**, and as a result, I can't get the check box normally.Tips System.ArgumentNullException.
What if I can improve the display speed and get the index of the check box correctly?
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you create a property `IsTextSelected` on your view model and bind it to `CheckBox.IsChecked` property?

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Select" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsTextSelected"} Click="TextSelected_Click"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Then you can check which items have `IsTextSelected` set to true.

```
private void TextSelected_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    deltextindex.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < textWmdg.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        var viewModel = textWmdg.Items[i] as YourViewModelType;
        if (viewModel.IsTextSelected)
        {
            deltextindex.Add(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my example, what should  “YourViewModelType” mean，thank you

Comment: In DataGrid you are binding ItemsSource="{Binding waterTexts}". What's the type of elements in waterTexts collection? YourViewModelType means the type of those elements inside waterTexts collection.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, which enabled me to solve the problem successfully. In addition, when Binding ischecked event, you need to add "updatesourcetrigger = PropertyChanged", otherwise it will not work.